# How to get data for user pemissions

Tags: design-patterns

I have been developing a *Case Management System*. I have the roles

- Manager,
- Operator,
- Technical Member and
- Case-categories.

So Manager can see all the cases, Operator can see the cases which he created and Technical Member can see the cases which he can access. So when I create Technical Member I check some case-categories which a Technical Member can see.

Is there any pattern for it that gets data for the user?
I have developed a check `if User.IsOperator Then`...
But I think it's not a good solution.